# Bad issue with Hibernate: records automatically added when querying for a list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using - Hibernate 4 - Spring 3

I'm facing a problem I can't understand: When I try to retrieve a list of objects in Hibernate, a different table of my Database is filled with rows. I suspect there's someting wrong with the "CASCADE" and "FETCHING" properties I have set, but I really can't understand.

Let me explain the problem.

Here there are 4 entities:

1. a User which has all the credentials like `username`, `isEnabled`, `Authorities List` and similar stuff
2. an Authority which records the role of the user
3. a ProfiledUser which has all the stuff related to `profile data`, `address data`, and a list of `checkups` as well, and finally
4. a Checkup which have some data and a reference to the user

I tried to model the following

[image]

here's the classes: **User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements UserDetails, DomainObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long id;
    //other stuff here
    Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="AUTHORITIES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
    public Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }   
}
```

**ProfiledUSer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROFILED_USERS")
public class ProfiledUser extends User{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //other stuff here. Everything with CASCADE ALL
    private Collection<Checkup> checkupMap = new HashSet<Checkup>();

    public ProfiledUser() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<Checkup> getCheckupMap() {
        return checkupMap;
    }

    public void setCheckupMap(Collection<Checkup> checkupMap) {
        this.checkupMap = checkupMap;
    }
}
```

**Checkup**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHECKUPS")
public class Checkup implements DomainObject{

    private long id;
    private ProfiledUser profiledUser;
    //other stuff here everyithing fetched EAGERLY
    private boolean pending = true;

    public Checkup() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="profiledUser")
    public ProfiledUser getProfiledUser() {
        return profiledUser;
    }

    public void setProfiledUser(ProfiledUser profiledUser) {
        this.profiledUser = profiledUser;
    }

    @Column(name="pending")
    public boolean isPending() {
        return pending;
    }

    public void setPending(boolean pending) {
        this.pending = pending;
    }
}
```

and finally **Authority**

```
@Embeddable
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String authority;  //Spring Security demands them to start with "ROLE_"

    public Authority() {
        super();
    }

    @Column(name="authority")
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.authority;
    }

    //the administer is the one allowed to change the users' role
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")
    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        if(!authority.startsWith("ROLE_"))
            authority= (new String("ROLE_")).concat(authority.toUpperCase());
        this.authority = authority.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Now the problem. When I try to retrieve a LIST of PENDING checkups (pending is a boolean attribute of a Checkup) doing the following

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Checkup> loadPendingCheckups()
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from " + objName + " where pending is true");
    List<Checkup> checkupList = query.list();
    if(checkupList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else
        return checkupList;
}
```

this method is from `CheckupDaoImpl` which is annotated with `@Transactional`.

Hibernate starts to delete and add a great amount of rows form the `Authority` table. For exmple it deletes the role `ROLE_USER` form the user 2 and adds is twice so that the number of `ROLE_USER` for the user 2 doubles with time: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ... and so on.
I really can't understand why asking for a SELECT it ends up with a WRITE operation!
Please help me because I really don't know where's the problem!

**EDIT:**

When I invoke a `loadPendingCheckups()` I can read the following in the console:

```
Hibernate: select checkup0_.id as id0_, checkup0_.date as date0_, checkup0_.ending_measurement as ending6_0_, checkup0_.mid_measurement as mid7_0_, checkup0_.pending as pending0_, checkup0_.physiology as physiology0_, checkup0_.profiledUser as profiled9_0_, checkup0_.quiet_measurement as quiet10_0_, checkup0_.maxTrainingFrequency as maxTrain4_0_, checkup0_.minTrainingFrequency as minTrain5_0_, checkup0_.scale_outcome as scale11_0_ from CHECKUPS checkup0_ where checkup0_.pending=1
Hibernate: select measuremen0_.id as id1_0_, measuremen0_.average_pressure as average2_1_0_, measuremen0_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_0_, measuremen0_.heart_rate as heart4_1_0_, measuremen0_.spO2 as spO5_1_0_, measuremen0_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_0_ from MEASUREMENTS measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select measuremen0_.id as id1_0_, measuremen0_.average_pressure as average2_1_0_, measuremen0_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_0_, measuremen0_.heart_rate as heart4_1_0_, measuremen0_.spO2 as spO5_1_0_, measuremen0_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_0_ from MEASUREMENTS measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select physiology0_.id as id2_0_, physiology0_.height as height2_0_, physiology0_.morphism_type as morphism3_2_0_, physiology0_.structure_type as structure4_2_0_, physiology0_.weight as weight2_0_ from PHYSIOLOGIES physiology0_ where physiology0_.id=?
Hibernate: select profiledus0_.id as id7_9_, profiledus0_1_.account_non_expired as account2_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.account_non_locked as account3_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.credentials_non_expired as credenti4_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.enabled as enabled7_9_, profiledus0_1_.password as password7_9_, profiledus0_1_.username as username7_9_, profiledus0_.address_data as address3_8_9_, profiledus0_.contact_data as contact4_8_9_, profiledus0_.personal_data as personal5_8_9_, profiledus0_.subscription_date as subscrip1_8_9_, authoritie1_.user_id as user1_7_11_, authoritie1_.authority as authority11_, addressdat2_.id as id4_0_, addressdat2_.country as country4_0_, addressdat2_.location as location4_0_, addressdat2_.street as street4_0_, addressdat2_.street_number as street5_4_0_, addressdat2_.zip_code as zip6_4_0_, checkupmap3_.profiledUser as profiled9_7_12_, checkupmap3_.id as id12_, checkupmap3_.id as id0_1_, checkupmap3_.date as date0_1_, checkupmap3_.ending_measurement as ending6_0_1_, checkupmap3_.mid_measurement as mid7_0_1_, checkupmap3_.pending as pending0_1_, checkupmap3_.physiology as physiology0_1_, checkupmap3_.profiledUser as profiled9_0_1_, checkupmap3_.quiet_measurement as quiet10_0_1_, checkupmap3_.maxTrainingFrequency as maxTrain4_0_1_, checkupmap3_.minTrainingFrequency as minTrain5_0_1_, checkupmap3_.scale_outcome as scale11_0_1_, measuremen4_.id as id1_2_, measuremen4_.average_pressure as average2_1_2_, measuremen4_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_2_, measuremen4_.heart_rate as heart4_1_2_, measuremen4_.spO2 as spO5_1_2_, measuremen4_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_2_, measuremen5_.id as id1_3_, measuremen5_.average_pressure as average2_1_3_, measuremen5_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_3_, measuremen5_.heart_rate as heart4_1_3_, measuremen5_.spO2 as spO5_1_3_, measuremen5_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_3_, physiology6_.id as id2_4_, physiology6_.height as height2_4_, physiology6_.morphism_type as morphism3_2_4_, physiology6_.structure_type as structure4_2_4_, physiology6_.weight as weight2_4_, measuremen7_.id as id1_5_, measuremen7_.average_pressure as average2_1_5_, measuremen7_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_5_, measuremen7_.heart_rate as heart4_1_5_, measuremen7_.spO2 as spO5_1_5_, measuremen7_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_5_, scaleoutco8_.id as id3_6_, scaleoutco8_.bmr as bmr3_6_, scaleoutco8_.body_fat as body3_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.metabolic_age as metabolic4_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.muscle_mass as muscle5_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.skeletal_mass as skeletal6_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.visceral_fat as visceral7_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.water as water3_6_, scaleoutco8_.weight as weight3_6_, contactdat9_.id as id5_7_, contactdat9_.email as email5_7_, contactdat9_.mobile as mobile5_7_, contactdat9_.phone as phone5_7_, personalda10_.id as id6_8_, personalda10_.birth_date as birth2_6_8_, personalda10_.name as name6_8_, personalda10_.second_name as second4_6_8_ from PROFILED_USERS profiledus0_ inner join USERS profiledus0_1_ on profiledus0_.id=profiledus0_1_.id left outer join AUTHORITIES authoritie1_ on profiledus0_.id=authoritie1_.user_id left outer join ADDRESS_DATA addressdat2_ on profiledus0_.address_data=addressdat2_.id left outer join CHECKUPS checkupmap3_ on profiledus0_.id=checkupmap3_.profiledUser left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen4_ on checkupmap3_.ending_measurement=measuremen4_.id left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen5_ on checkupmap3_.mid_measurement=measuremen5_.id left outer join PHYSIOLOGIES physiology6_ on checkupmap3_.physiology=physiology6_.id left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen7_ on checkupmap3_.quiet_measurement=measuremen7_.id left outer join SCALE_OUTCOMES scaleoutco8_ on checkupmap3_.scale_outcome=scaleoutco8_.id left outer join CONTACT_DATA contactdat9_ on profiledus0_.contact_data=contactdat9_.id left outer join PERSONAL_DATA personalda10_ on profiledus0_.personal_data=personalda10_.id where profiledus0_.id=?
Hibernate: select measuremen0_.id as id1_0_, measuremen0_.average_pressure as average2_1_0_, measuremen0_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_0_, measuremen0_.heart_rate as heart4_1_0_, measuremen0_.spO2 as spO5_1_0_, measuremen0_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_0_ from MEASUREMENTS measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select measuremen0_.id as id1_0_, measuremen0_.average_pressure as average2_1_0_, measuremen0_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_0_, measuremen0_.heart_rate as heart4_1_0_, measuremen0_.spO2 as spO5_1_0_, measuremen0_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_0_ from MEASUREMENTS measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select physiology0_.id as id2_0_, physiology0_.height as height2_0_, physiology0_.morphism_type as morphism3_2_0_, physiology0_.structure_type as structure4_2_0_, physiology0_.weight as weight2_0_ from PHYSIOLOGIES physiology0_ where physiology0_.id=?
Hibernate: select profiledus0_.id as id7_9_, profiledus0_1_.account_non_expired as account2_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.account_non_locked as account3_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.credentials_non_expired as credenti4_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.enabled as enabled7_9_, profiledus0_1_.password as password7_9_, profiledus0_1_.username as username7_9_, profiledus0_.address_data as address3_8_9_, profiledus0_.contact_data as contact4_8_9_, profiledus0_.personal_data as personal5_8_9_, profiledus0_.subscription_date as subscrip1_8_9_, authoritie1_.user_id as user1_7_11_, authoritie1_.authority as authority11_, addressdat2_.id as id4_0_, addressdat2_.country as country4_0_, addressdat2_.location as location4_0_, addressdat2_.street as street4_0_, addressdat2_.street_number as street5_4_0_, addressdat2_.zip_code as zip6_4_0_, checkupmap3_.profiledUser as profiled9_7_12_, checkupmap3_.id as id12_, checkupmap3_.id as id0_1_, checkupmap3_.date as date0_1_, checkupmap3_.ending_measurement as ending6_0_1_, checkupmap3_.mid_measurement as mid7_0_1_, checkupmap3_.pending as pending0_1_, checkupmap3_.physiology as physiology0_1_, checkupmap3_.profiledUser as profiled9_0_1_, checkupmap3_.quiet_measurement as quiet10_0_1_, checkupmap3_.maxTrainingFrequency as maxTrain4_0_1_, checkupmap3_.minTrainingFrequency as minTrain5_0_1_, checkupmap3_.scale_outcome as scale11_0_1_, measuremen4_.id as id1_2_, measuremen4_.average_pressure as average2_1_2_, measuremen4_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_2_, measuremen4_.heart_rate as heart4_1_2_, measuremen4_.spO2 as spO5_1_2_, measuremen4_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_2_, measuremen5_.id as id1_3_, measuremen5_.average_pressure as average2_1_3_, measuremen5_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_3_, measuremen5_.heart_rate as heart4_1_3_, measuremen5_.spO2 as spO5_1_3_, measuremen5_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_3_, physiology6_.id as id2_4_, physiology6_.height as height2_4_, physiology6_.morphism_type as morphism3_2_4_, physiology6_.structure_type as structure4_2_4_, physiology6_.weight as weight2_4_, measuremen7_.id as id1_5_, measuremen7_.average_pressure as average2_1_5_, measuremen7_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_5_, measuremen7_.heart_rate as heart4_1_5_, measuremen7_.spO2 as spO5_1_5_, measuremen7_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_5_, scaleoutco8_.id as id3_6_, scaleoutco8_.bmr as bmr3_6_, scaleoutco8_.body_fat as body3_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.metabolic_age as metabolic4_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.muscle_mass as muscle5_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.skeletal_mass as skeletal6_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.visceral_fat as visceral7_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.water as water3_6_, scaleoutco8_.weight as weight3_6_, contactdat9_.id as id5_7_, contactdat9_.email as email5_7_, contactdat9_.mobile as mobile5_7_, contactdat9_.phone as phone5_7_, personalda10_.id as id6_8_, personalda10_.birth_date as birth2_6_8_, personalda10_.name as name6_8_, personalda10_.second_name as second4_6_8_ from PROFILED_USERS profiledus0_ inner join USERS profiledus0_1_ on profiledus0_.id=profiledus0_1_.id left outer join AUTHORITIES authoritie1_ on profiledus0_.id=authoritie1_.user_id left outer join ADDRESS_DATA addressdat2_ on profiledus0_.address_data=addressdat2_.id left outer join CHECKUPS checkupmap3_ on profiledus0_.id=checkupmap3_.profiledUser left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen4_ on checkupmap3_.ending_measurement=measuremen4_.id left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen5_ on checkupmap3_.mid_measurement=measuremen5_.id left outer join PHYSIOLOGIES physiology6_ on checkupmap3_.physiology=physiology6_.id left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen7_ on checkupmap3_.quiet_measurement=measuremen7_.id left outer join SCALE_OUTCOMES scaleoutco8_ on checkupmap3_.scale_outcome=scaleoutco8_.id left outer join CONTACT_DATA contactdat9_ on profiledus0_.contact_data=contactdat9_.id left outer join PERSONAL_DATA personalda10_ on profiledus0_.personal_data=personalda10_.id where profiledus0_.id=?
Hibernate: select measuremen0_.id as id1_0_, measuremen0_.average_pressure as average2_1_0_, measuremen0_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_0_, measuremen0_.heart_rate as heart4_1_0_, measuremen0_.spO2 as spO5_1_0_, measuremen0_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_0_ from MEASUREMENTS measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select measuremen0_.id as id1_0_, measuremen0_.average_pressure as average2_1_0_, measuremen0_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_0_, measuremen0_.heart_rate as heart4_1_0_, measuremen0_.spO2 as spO5_1_0_, measuremen0_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_0_ from MEASUREMENTS measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select physiology0_.id as id2_0_, physiology0_.height as height2_0_, physiology0_.morphism_type as morphism3_2_0_, physiology0_.structure_type as structure4_2_0_, physiology0_.weight as weight2_0_ from PHYSIOLOGIES physiology0_ where physiology0_.id=?
Hibernate: select profiledus0_.id as id7_9_, profiledus0_1_.account_non_expired as account2_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.account_non_locked as account3_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.credentials_non_expired as credenti4_7_9_, profiledus0_1_.enabled as enabled7_9_, profiledus0_1_.password as password7_9_, profiledus0_1_.username as username7_9_, profiledus0_.address_data as address3_8_9_, profiledus0_.contact_data as contact4_8_9_, profiledus0_.personal_data as personal5_8_9_, profiledus0_.subscription_date as subscrip1_8_9_, authoritie1_.user_id as user1_7_11_, authoritie1_.authority as authority11_, addressdat2_.id as id4_0_, addressdat2_.country as country4_0_, addressdat2_.location as location4_0_, addressdat2_.street as street4_0_, addressdat2_.street_number as street5_4_0_, addressdat2_.zip_code as zip6_4_0_, checkupmap3_.profiledUser as profiled9_7_12_, checkupmap3_.id as id12_, checkupmap3_.id as id0_1_, checkupmap3_.date as date0_1_, checkupmap3_.ending_measurement as ending6_0_1_, checkupmap3_.mid_measurement as mid7_0_1_, checkupmap3_.pending as pending0_1_, checkupmap3_.physiology as physiology0_1_, checkupmap3_.profiledUser as profiled9_0_1_, checkupmap3_.quiet_measurement as quiet10_0_1_, checkupmap3_.maxTrainingFrequency as maxTrain4_0_1_, checkupmap3_.minTrainingFrequency as minTrain5_0_1_, checkupmap3_.scale_outcome as scale11_0_1_, measuremen4_.id as id1_2_, measuremen4_.average_pressure as average2_1_2_, measuremen4_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_2_, measuremen4_.heart_rate as heart4_1_2_, measuremen4_.spO2 as spO5_1_2_, measuremen4_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_2_, measuremen5_.id as id1_3_, measuremen5_.average_pressure as average2_1_3_, measuremen5_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_3_, measuremen5_.heart_rate as heart4_1_3_, measuremen5_.spO2 as spO5_1_3_, measuremen5_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_3_, physiology6_.id as id2_4_, physiology6_.height as height2_4_, physiology6_.morphism_type as morphism3_2_4_, physiology6_.structure_type as structure4_2_4_, physiology6_.weight as weight2_4_, measuremen7_.id as id1_5_, measuremen7_.average_pressure as average2_1_5_, measuremen7_.diastolic_pressure as diastolic3_1_5_, measuremen7_.heart_rate as heart4_1_5_, measuremen7_.spO2 as spO5_1_5_, measuremen7_.systolic_pressure as systolic6_1_5_, scaleoutco8_.id as id3_6_, scaleoutco8_.bmr as bmr3_6_, scaleoutco8_.body_fat as body3_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.metabolic_age as metabolic4_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.muscle_mass as muscle5_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.skeletal_mass as skeletal6_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.visceral_fat as visceral7_3_6_, scaleoutco8_.water as water3_6_, scaleoutco8_.weight as weight3_6_, contactdat9_.id as id5_7_, contactdat9_.email as email5_7_, contactdat9_.mobile as mobile5_7_, contactdat9_.phone as phone5_7_, personalda10_.id as id6_8_, personalda10_.birth_date as birth2_6_8_, personalda10_.name as name6_8_, personalda10_.second_name as second4_6_8_ from PROFILED_USERS profiledus0_ inner join USERS profiledus0_1_ on profiledus0_.id=profiledus0_1_.id left outer join AUTHORITIES authoritie1_ on profiledus0_.id=authoritie1_.user_id left outer join ADDRESS_DATA addressdat2_ on profiledus0_.address_data=addressdat2_.id left outer join CHECKUPS checkupmap3_ on profiledus0_.id=checkupmap3_.profiledUser left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen4_ on checkupmap3_.ending_measurement=measuremen4_.id left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen5_ on checkupmap3_.mid_measurement=measuremen5_.id left outer join PHYSIOLOGIES physiology6_ on checkupmap3_.physiology=physiology6_.id left outer join MEASUREMENTS measuremen7_ on checkupmap3_.quiet_measurement=measuremen7_.id left outer join SCALE_OUTCOMES scaleoutco8_ on checkupmap3_.scale_outcome=scaleoutco8_.id left outer join CONTACT_DATA contactdat9_ on profiledus0_.contact_data=contactdat9_.id left outer join PERSONAL_DATA personalda10_ on profiledus0_.personal_data=personalda10_.id where profiledus0_.id=?
Hibernate: delete from AUTHORITIES where user_id=? and authority=?
Hibernate: insert into AUTHORITIES (user_id, authority) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from AUTHORITIES where user_id=? and authority=?
...// a very lot of these
Hibernate: insert into AUTHORITIES (user_id, authority) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AUTHORITIES (user_id, authority) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AUTHORITIES (user_id, authority) values (?, ?)
//a very lot of these
```

the physiology, measurement etc, is the stuff inside a checkup. I think it's ok it is retrieved. But after that, it is triggered the massive deletion & insert inside the AUTHORITY table.

**EDIT 2:**
It seems the problem is solved switching form `@ElementCollection` to `@OneToMany` relations between User and Authority. Luckily, I'm designing the database and this modification is allowed for me. The problem seems to be disappeared but still I didn't figure out the rationale behind the strange behaviour of the ORM.
More precisely, the most weird thing is that when I was asking to retrieve Checkups form db Hibernate triggered an incredible amount of

1. deletion of Authority items
2. insertion of Authority items

If anyone can point the thing out it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that it's a cause of your problem, but your bidirectional relationship between `ProfiledUser` and `Checkup` is configured incorrectly.

Bidirectional one-to-many relationships are configured as follows:

- One side is annotated with `@ManyToOne`, another one - with `@OneToMany`
- `@OneToMany` must have a `mappedBy` attribute that points to corresponding `@ManyToOne` property
- Physical mapping annotations (`@JoinColumn`) should be at `@ManyToOne` side

Something like this:

```
public class ProfiledUser extends User{
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "profiledUser")
    public Collection<Checkup> getCheckupMap() {
        return checkupMap;
    }
    ...
}

public class Checkup implements DomainObject {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="profiledUser")
    public ProfiledUser getProfiledUser() {
        return profiledUser;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you earned my everlasting gratitude! With your corrections, the code seems to work properly. Actually, I think it's wise to test my application a little more before celebrations. By the way no weird db population at this time. A little thought: I know that it is necessary to know a tool (hibernate) before using it, but sometimes the documentation is overwhelming and the time is short. It would be nice to be supported by hibernate in case of weird configurations (like mine). Thank you!

Comment: unluckily, the problem comes back.